# Java grade calculator. I need some help starting this class

Tags: java

Java grade converter. How can I start coding this class?

I'm doing a project for my Java course that is a grade converter. I'm looking for some pointers to start coding this class called "grade." One of my instructions is: Use a class named Grade to store the data for each grade. This class should include these three methods: 
public void setNumber(int number) 
public int getNumber() 
public String getLetter()
The Grade class should have two constructors. The first one should accept no parameters and set the initial value of the number instance variable to zero. The second should accept an integer value and use it to set the initial value of the number instance variable.
I have the class created already, but how can I go about coding the constructors?

```
public class Grade {

int number;
String value;

public static void setNumber(int number) {


}
 public int getNumber() { 


}
```

Comment: So where is your code to date? Someone isn't going to start it for you, show us how far you've achieved first.

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly. Include your code --- this is not a free code writing service! *You* need to write the code and when you run into problems, you can ask specific questions about the code *you*  have written. What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: I put the code in that I have so far.

Comment: Try following the instructions; “Use a class named Grade”. OK, you did that. “This class should include these three methods ...” Try doing that next.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is a block of code that initialises the newly created object. In java, the default construction is called no-arg constructor. When you create an object like **new Grade()** it will invoke the default constructor. You can have different constructors with different parameters. Having such is called constructor overloading. In your case, you many need to do something like the one below.

```
class Grade {
    int number;

    public Grade() {
        this.number = 0;
    }

    public Grade(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```